# Sketch to CSS - Radial Gradient Css Export Problem

Tags: css, sass, styles, sketchapp, sketch-3

My English is a little bad. Sorry.
There is a design prepared in the Sketch program.
I couldn't spill the radial gradiant correctly into the css code. How do I get the same radial gradiant appearance?

Screenshots :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DrNp.jpg -
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke7Il.jpg

**Radial Gradiant Height :** 1000px

**Radial Gradiant Color :** #3F46AD (Opacity 10%)

**Note:** The "Copy CSS Attributes (Sketch)" feature did not export correctly;

HTML :

```
<div class="gradient-bg-wrapper">

</div>

<div class="text-wrapper">
    test test test
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.gradient-bg-wrapper{
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: radial-gradient(50% 124%, #3F46AD 75%, #FFFFFF 100%);
    opacity: 0.1;
 }
```

Comment: you can find all what you need by checking the DOC : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient and the spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#radial-gradients

Comment: @TemaniAfif First of all thank you. I tried a lot. But I didn't get the same export. :(

Comment: Having the same problem.. radial gradient is not the same when exported as CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.gradient-bg-wrapper{
    height: 500px;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(63,70,173,0.1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.1) 100%);
 }
```

```html
<div class="gradient-bg-wrapper">
</div>

<div class="text-wrapper">
    test test test
</div>
```